# closing a project in database by clicking a button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, database, sweetalert

I need to close a project on database by clicking the reject button. This is my codes for the ui of the reject button. and on the comment part is the code I have in another file that can close the project on db just by clicking the door icon. I'm a bit confused on how I can incorporate database in the `sweetalertrejects` function. Can anybody help me with this?

```
<script>
    function sweetalertrejects(){
        swal("This button means closing the task. You will not be able to revert this action. Do you wish to continue?", {
            icon: "info",
            buttons: {
                cancel: "Cancel",
                catch: {
                    text: "Yes, close this task",
                    value: "cancel",
                },

            },
        })
        .then((value) => {
            switch (value) {
                case "cancel":
                    swal("Closed!", "Task has been closed.", "success").then(()=>{
                        document.getElementById("approve_button").disabled = true;
                        document.getElementById("return").disabled = true;
                    });
                    break;
                default:
                    swal("Task has not been closed.");
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

This is the code I have on another page where it can close the project just by clicking the door button.

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST["closetask"])) {
    $close_task_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["close_task_id"]);
    $sql = "UPDATE task SET task_status='closed' WHERE id_task='$close_task_id'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    if ($result) {
        $_SESSION['success'] = "Task closed";
        $_SESSION['text'] = "Task has been closed successfully";
        $_SESSION['icon'] = "success";
    } else {
        $_SESSION['success'] = "Error";
        $_SESSION['text'] = "Unkown error, please try again";
        $_SESSION['icon'] = "error";
    }
}

if (isset($_POST["opentask"])) {
    $close_task_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["close_task_id"]);
    $sql = "UPDATE task SET task_status='open' WHERE id_task='$close_task_id'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    if ($result) {
        $_SESSION['success'] = "Task opened";
        $_SESSION['text'] = "Task has been opened successfully";
        $_SESSION['icon'] = "success";
    } else {
        $_SESSION['success'] = "Error";
        $_SESSION['text'] = "Unkown error, please try again";
        $_SESSION['icon'] = "error";
    }
}

?>

<?php

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    if ($row['task_status'] == 'open'){
        $check_task = '
            <form action="tasks-list.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="text" name="close_task_id" class="form-control" value="' . $row["id_task"] . '" hidden>
                <button type="submit" name="closetask" class="btn btn-success btn-circle btn-sm mr-2" >
                    <i class="fas fa-door-open"></i>
                </button>
            </form>
        ';
    }else {
        $check_task = '
            <form action="tasks-list.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="hidden" name="close_task_id" class="form-control" value="' . $row["id_task"] . '" >
                <button type="submit" name="opentask" class="btn btn-error btn-circle btn-sm">
                    <i class="fas fa-door-closed"></i>
                </button>
            </form>
        ';
    }
}
```

Comment: Trigger the update query thru ajax in the swal default block please.

Comment: hi! how do i do that?